# What is designed to go into holes and always has a hole in it?

Tags: riddle, word

What is designed to go into holes and always has a hole in it?

It fits this pattern:

`S` `_` `_` `_` `_` `_` `_` `_`

Comment: This seems fantastically broad. See https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4561/4833 for guidance.

Comment: @Sneftel The votes suggest you're right, but the answers suggest otherwise. I edited the question to include *always* and so far I see one answer fitting that requirement. The hints are there to help, but I'm happy to remove them.

Comment: A drinking straw. A subway train. A lock cylinder. A 50-yen coin. A catheter. It's easy to come up with answers to this question, disregarding the hints. There's no problem with adding hints to a question, but the question should stand alone.

Comment: I would argue that some of those weren't *designed to go into holes*, rather they *can*, but I take your point.

Comment: So just edit, change the hints to be part of the riddle, and BAM, you have a great riddle.

Comment: i have a good answer but seems inappropriate.

Comment: A doughnut goes in your cake-hole.

Comment: @oMiKeY I have no such qualms:   "schmucks"  :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is it a

> shoelace?

because

> Shoelaces are threaded through holes in a shoe, and the word 's**ho**e**l**ac**e**' always contains the word 'hole'

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: And <spoiler> starts with S. +1

Comment: Spoiler in this comment! I object that it is too arcane an expectation to impose on a riddle solver that they must come up with an intra-anagram.

Answer (score 15):

Are you a

> Doughnut

Because

> It goes in your mouth-hole and it has a hole.

Also

> It has 8 letters.

Comment: Upvoted as that totally works. Added Hint 2 as it's not what I was looking for.

Comment: I could add "always" has a hole in it to the question (since some of yours don't always!).

Comment: https://bit.ly/2I8iNHo

Answer (score 4):

It's:

> syringes

because:

> They're designed to make a hole to go into and have a hole to squeeze medicine through

Or with hints removed and fitting `What is` better:

> a syringe.

Comment: I would argue that *What is* suggests a singular word rather than plural?

Comment: Valid point, know it's a bit of stretch there buts fits so well otherwise had to give it a go

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> an embroidery needle, which goes through holes in the backing material

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the main body of the puzzle should be sufficient to uniquely specify an answer. Hints should be for making it easier to find that answer, not eliminating duplicate answers (that is, it's not valid to reject an answer because it fails to satisfy the hints). An answer that satisfies the main body of the question is

> Shovel

Comment: https://mobileimages.lowes.com/product/converted/755625/755625008961.jpg

Comment: *Horn* Shovels are used for *making* holes, and do not always have a hole in them.